# Sort Hashmap by value and then alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, comparator

I am creating a word frequency program which works good with counting the words. I am using a hashmap to store the word frequencies. I use the word as the key and the count as the value. However, I want to sort the hashMap at the end first by the word frequency and then by key alphabetically like this:

```
it - 2
of - 2
the - 2
times- 2 
was - 2  
best- 1 
worst - 1
```

I am guessing that I will need a custom Comparator, but I have no idea how to construct it. Please, any suggestions?

Comment: You can't, but try searching for "[java sort hashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+sort+hashmap)" to find a bunch of other questions asking exactly the same question.

Comment: @Andreas - I'm not sure it is seeing as he wants to sort based upon the value *and* the key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a sorted `HashMap`, as is stated in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> ... This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

You will have to put it into a different structure that maintains the order you want it to.

Based on what you provided, it looks like you have a few criteria for your order:

1. sorted by the `Map.Entry` **value**, in descending order
2. sorted by the `Map.Entry` **key**, in ascending order

You can make use of the `Stream` API, along with the useful `Comparator`s from `Map.Entry`.

```
final HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("it", 2);
map.put("of", 2);
map.put("the", 2);
map.put("times", 2);
map.put("was", 2);
map.put("best", 1);
map.put("worst", 1);

System.out.println("No Guaranteed Order:");
map.entrySet().stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println);


System.out.println();
System.out.println("With Ordering:");
map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()
                        .reversed()
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

And the output:

```
No Guaranteed Order:
the=2
times=2
of=2
was=2
best=1
worst=1
it=2

With Ordering:
it=2
of=2
the=2
times=2
was=2
best=1
worst=1
```

Comment: This is really an elegant solution to the problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as you're only needing to do this sort once, I'd suggest that you create a `Result` object that holds your `String` and `Integer` values and implements `Comparable` (keep the key the same). When you need to sort your results, just call `values()` on the `HashMap` and then sort them.

Main.java

```
import java.util.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        HashMap<String, Result> hm = new HashMap<String, Result>();
        addTo(hm, "to");
        addTo(hm, "be");
        addTo(hm, "or");
        addTo(hm, "not");
        addTo(hm, "to");
        addTo(hm, "be");

        List<Result> results = new ArrayList(hm.values());
        Collections.sort(results);
        for(Result result : results)
        {
            System.out.println(result.getValue() + " - " +result.getCount());
        }       
    }

    public static void addTo(HashMap<String, Result> hm, String entry)
    {
        if(! hm.containsKey(entry))
        {
            Result result = new Result(entry);
            hm.put(entry, new Result(entry));
        }
        hm.get(entry).increment();
    }
}
```

Result.java

```
public class Result implements Comparable
    {
        private int count;
        private String value;

        public Result(String value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.count = 0;
        }

        public String getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return count;
        }

        public void increment()
        {
            count++;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o)
        {
            Result result = (Result)o;
            if(getCount() == result.getCount())
            {
                return getValue().compareTo(result.getValue());
            }
            else
            {
                // Want larger values to be on-top, so reverse traditional sort order
                return ((Integer)result.getCount()).compareTo((Integer)getCount());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you  so much,  I am going to try your suggestion tomorrow morning. Really appreciate the time that you spend to help me. :)